# How can I use Objects in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created this function `get_flight_by_date` which extracts flight data from an API: the number of flight, the departure, the destination, ...

When I call this function I need to display the destination as well as the departure what I did it was this:

```js
function get_flight_by_date(date, callback) {
  let request = require("request");
  let url =
    "http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=xxxxxx&flight_status=scheduled";

  request(url, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error:", error);
      callback(err);
    } else {
      let vol = JSON.parse(body);
      num = vol.pagination.limits;
      result = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        flight_date = vol.data[i].flight_date;

        one_flight = {
          number: vol.data[i].flight.number,
          date: vol.data[i].flight_date,
          departure: vol.data[i].departure.timezone,
          arrival: vol.data[i].arrival.timezone,
          from: vol.data[i].departure.airport,
          to: vol.data[i].arrival.airport
        };
        result.push(one_flight);
      }
      callback(null, result);
    }
  });
}
function get_route_by_flight_date(date, req, res) {
  get_flight_by_date(date, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error");
    } else {
      var links = [];
      result.map(result => {
        links.push(
          "from " +
            " " +
            result[0][departure] +
            " " +
            "to" +
            " " +
            result[0][arrival]
        );
      });

      console.log(links);
    }
  });
}
get_route_by_flight_date("2020-11-02");
```

What I got in the console is: `ReferenceError: departure is not defined`

Comment: `get_route_by_flight_date` never has access to `departure`. They exist in different scopes.

Comment: `result.map(result => {` where you reference `result[0]` is very hard to read intent.

Comment: So what should I do please ?

Comment: its would be `result.departure`, your map'ing (which should be forEach) over an array, you should console.log(result) before using to be sure you're accessing the correct things

Comment: Perhaps this `result[0][departure] ` should be `result[0].departure`.   The structure `[departure]` is looking for a variable named `departure` which does not exist in that function.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick read, it looks like the error might relate to `result[0][departure]`. Maybe that needs to be `result[0]["departure"]` (and the same for `result[0][arrival]` which would be `result[0]["arrival"]`).

Answer (score 0):

get_flight_by_date is returning an array that you are looping over in 6th line of get_route_by_flight_date.

So, rather have the code as following.

```
function get_route_by_flight_date(date, req, res) {
  get_flight_by_date(date, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error");
    } else {
      var links = [];
      results.map(result => {
        links.push(
          "from " +
            " " +
            result.departure +
            " " +
            "to" +
            " " +
            result.arrival
        );
      });

      console.log(links);
    }
  });
}
```

Changes noted below:

- I have changed the input from 'result' to 'results' to make it more meaningful.
- When you loop, the iterated-object is named as 'result' - as-is in your code.
- IMPORTANT: result is a JSON-object. So, access the departure & arrival as result.arrival and result.departure instead of result[arrival] and result[departure]. In the latter case, the code is looking for a variable named departure and arrival, while we intend to refer the keys of the object, that are rather represented as keys.